# Parse and output TypoScript in TypoScript

Tags: parsing, typo3, typoscript

I have extended the pages table with one text field named *TypoScript*.

My intention was to use this field in TMENUs so that I can display arbitrary content as — for example — a dropdown for that page.

I know how to parse and output TypoScript in an extension, but I'm not sure if there's a way to do that in TypoScript alone.

So, in summary: Is it possible to have a TypoScript string and parse and output it in TypoScript?

Comment: Yes...  Oh, wait.  You want to know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a user function for that.

To be more specific, you have to use either the `USER` or the `USER_INT` content object.

Comment: ...which is an legitimate answer, as maryisdead already knows how to parse typoscript in php. Hurray for userFunc!

Comment: Agreed. Just thought I've missed something fundamental. userFunc it is then.